# Dynamically update through the row using nodejs

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server

This is my update SQL using SQL Server;

```
const sql = require("mssql");
  async updateContactbyID(id, notes) {
    await this.connect();
    const request = this.poolconnection.request();
    const result = await request
      .input("contactID", sql.Int, id)
      .input("notes", sql.NVarChar(255), notes).query(`UPDATE [user].[contacts]
    set notes=@notes
    where contactId=@contactID`);

    return result.rowsAffected[0];
  }
```

my index.js call database:

```
const Database = require("../model/database");
const config = require("../config/config");
const database = new Database(config);
    const updateContact = await database.updateContactbyID(
      contact_data.id,
      contact_data.notes
    );
    console.log("this is updated.", updateContact );
    database.disconnect();
```

The above SQL is updating with the specific column name by setting set.

But, I would like to update the table row with dynamically. For instance: I want to update the row without specific the column name. So, I would like to update the table row no matter how many columns have each table.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Dupe of [Dynamically insert through the table using nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76503401/dynamically-insert-through-the-table-using-nodejs). Please don't post questions multiple times, it won't get you answers faster.